# NSubstitute CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException

Tags: nsubstitute

I'm using NSubstitute to mock a class by `PartsOf()` method (I need some of the methods to work). It looks like this:

```
var mock = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyWorker>();
mock.Start().Returns(void);
```

A simple code almost like from the NSubstitute's documentation, but I'm getting this exception instead: `"An exception of type 'NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException'
occurred in NSubstitute.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not find a call to return from."`

What's the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took me some time to figure it out. When using `ForPartsOf()` the mocked method must be `virtual`! That solves the problem with the `CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException` exception.